# Retreiving data from cloud firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to receive my data from cloud firestore for the very first time but I am neither getting any error nor any output ..Please help
Here is the screenshot of the output that i am not receiving anything except a single dot on screen.

**https://ibb.co/LPzWZDR**

I have not used service here, called it in the component itself

html file

```
 <ul>
   <li class="text" *ngFor="let item of items | async">{{item.name}}</li>
 </ul>
```

.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  items: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(db: AngularFirestore){
    this.items = db.collection('items').valueChanges();
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule ,FirestoreSettingsToken} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
    ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase,'asd'),
    AngularFirestoreModule,  // imports firebase/firestore, only needed for database features
    AngularFireAuthModule,   // imports firebase/auth, only needed for auth features,
    AngularFireStorageModule // imports firebase/storage only needed for storage features
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: FirestoreSettingsToken, useValue: {} }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: There's lots you're not showing us, including 1) what's an "item"?, 2) Did you create a database on your Google Firebase dashboard?  3) Did you copy the database key into your environment.ts?  Etc. etc.  SUGGESTION: Try a simple Angular/Firebase "hello world" with this tutorial: https://alligator.io/angular/cloud-firestore-angularfire/

Comment: @paulsm4 well can u check it here https://ibb.co/56FVFXg i am receiving response in console but unable to render it in html component

Comment: OK: that's a good data point.  At least we know 1) Angular is communicating with Firebase, and 2) It seems to be getting *something* back.  Q: Have you expanded the output in your IDE, to see exactly *what* you're getting back?  Is there a at least one "object" element, and does it have a ".name" property?  Q: Have you looked in your Google Dashboard to see if there's any data in your database?